# Entity Framework code first double FK as PK

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I need to map some entities using Fntity Framework code-first using the Fluent API.

I have a `Driver` and a `RacingVehicle`. I need a `Driver` to be in only one `RacingVehicle`, and a `RacingVehicle` to have only one `Driver`.

Booth classes refer to a `Contract` that connects them (Association Class?).
A `Contract` shows some extra info: How many years the contract between the `Driver` and his `RacingVehicle` will last.

My current code:

```cs
public class Driver
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    // others properties
    public virtual Contract Contract { get; protected set; }
}

public class RacingVehicle
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public int Number { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; protected set; }
    // others properties
    public virtual Contract Contract { get; protected set; }
}

public class Contract
{
    public virtual Driver Driver { get; protected set; }
    public virtual RacingVehicle RacingVehicle { get; protected set; }
    public int SeasonsRemaining { get; protected set; }
}
```

I will access the `RacingVehicle` from `Driver`, only through `Contract` (vice-versa). Something like this:

```cs
var teamName = ayrtonSenna.Contract.RacingVehicle.Team.Name;
var driverName = mcLaren.Contract.Driver.Name;
```

I'll have a `ContractManager` service class to manage those contracts.

I believe the `Contract` class must have mapped as PK, the FK from `Driver` and `RacingVehicle`, right?

So, how can I map this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd normally configure complex primary keys like this in the `OnModelCreating()` method of the context class, like so:

```
public class Contract
{
    public int DriverId { get; set; }
    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
    public int RacingVehicleId { get; set; }
    public virtual RacingVehicle RacingVehicle { get; set; }
    public int SeasonsRemaining { get; set; }
}

public class RacingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RacingVehicle> RacingVehicles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }

    public override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>().HasKey(contract => new { contract.DriverId, contract.RacingVehicleId });
    }
}
```

However, this has the implications that you can't add duplicate entries. So if a driver "Bob" gets a contract with McLaren, then when the contract ends he gets another contract with McLaren again, you'll have to delete the old contract, or overwrite it, in order to store the details of the new contract. If you don't care about the history, and are only interested in *current* contracts, then this setup is fine. If you want the full history, you have to give each contract a unique id, or add *code* to check that your contracts don't overlap. You can't easily enforce that through just a primary key.

Comment: _"you'll have to delete the old contract"_

Yes. That's exactly the idea. I will only have in DB, the current contracts. I'll try here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set this up when configuring your `DBContext` (see [the documentation for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext)).

In short, given your class...

```
public class Contract
{
    public virtual Driver Driver { get; protected set; }
    public virtual RacingVehicle RacingVehicle { get; protected set; }
    public int SeasonsRemaining { get; protected set; }
}
```

..you should be able to specify composite keys according to the following pattern:

```
class YourContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.Driver, c.RacingVehicle });
    }

    // ...
}
```

Note however that this refers to the objects `Driver` and `RacingVehicle`, and not to a simple value like a `string` or an `int`, so I'm not entirely sure how that would work (it's been a while since I worked with EF).

If this turns out to be a problem, I can think of two alternatives to try: Either  refer directly to the `Id` field of each object:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.Driver.Id, c.RacingVehicle.Id });
```

...or add the fields `DriverId` and `RacingVehicleId` to the `Contract` class, and use them directly:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.DriverId, c.RacingVehicleId });
```

---

**Another option** would be to add a new separate `Id` for `Contract`, and use that as a primary key. That would perhaps be a better solution in the long run from an architectural point of view; it would separate the concerns (driver and vehicle) more from each other, and would support e.g. a future situation where you'd like two drivers (a backup driver?) for a single vehicle.

This would also let you keep a history of driver-vehicle relationships over time (just add from- and to-dates for each contract). Your current solution could support that too, but then each driver could only drive a single vehicle a single time; you can never give the same driver a new contract without also changing the car.

The downside would be that you would have to implement explicit logic to check for driver-vehicle relationships, but that should not be too hard, and may well be worth it for the other benefits.

Comment: _"to add a new separate Id for Contract"_: I thought about it. Sometimes I like to try the hardest way, it's true, to learn different scenarios, hehe
 _"a better solution in the long run from an architectural point of view_: You are completely right. But for a while, the "contract" only serves to know which driver is in the vehicle. I could put a property Driver in Vehicle class, and the ContractManager would ensure Vehicle-Driver is unique and/or a Driver only runs in a single Vehicle... But I needed the "SeasonsRemaining" info. So I decide to do this way.
Thx for the answer, I'll try here.

Comment: @MaxDolabella Well if you want to simplify it that way, why not go all the way and add `CurrentDriver`and `CurrentDriverLastSeason` (tip: Use a date instead of an int; that way it will still be correct next year, or the year after without needing updates)? Otherwise, if you're going to "improve" the design by using a separate contract class, why not do it in a more complete manner at once? Then you'll be able to support multiple contracts per vehicle, per driver, as well as history.